# How does one specify a newline as a "before-code" in the titleformat command?

Tags: line-breaking, titlesec

(`titlesec`-Package)

It seems to me that inserting anything like `\\` or `\newline` in any of the fields provided by `titleformat` and `titlespacing` result in any of the following:

- The newline sometimes doesn't occur, "no line to end"-error.
- The field requires a length, not a command
- The newline is placed after the number, not before the entire title/section.

I really have no idea what to do here.

EDIT: To clarify, I'd like this:

```
  Lorem ipsum
 {
2{
  1 SECTION (IN CAPS TO EMPHASIZE IN THIS TEXT, NOT REALLY IN CAPS)
1{
  Lorem ipsum etc.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you're trying to do? This way it'll be much easier to diagnose and solve your problem :)

Comment: why would you need a newline _before_ a title???? It is very hard to understand your question. Are you trying to adjust the vertical space before the title?

Comment: Yes, trying to adjust the space before to two lines.

Comment: so just specify the length in the space-before field in  the title format specification, vertical spacing and linebreaks have almost nothing in common.

Comment: OK, but what is the spacing unit for ~1 line?

Comment: you could (but probably shouldn't) use `2\baselineskip` but normally spacing around headings is specified as "stretchy" space to help with page breaking rather than a fixed multiple of the baselineskip

Comment: note your question would have been clearer (and would still be easier to answer) if you had provided a small one-page document with a section title specification that did not work as you expected, someone could then easily have fixed your declaration and run your test document.

Comment: As it stands, the question does not show any code one could base an answer on. It is unclear and probably won't help anyone in the future. The answer below is of the sort *don't do stuff like that*. As the problem is fixed i vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I needed was the length `\baselineskip`, I didn't know or remeber that.

That is, in the `\titlespacing` command, I'd set the parameters to `n\baselineskip` to achieve n empty lines of seperation in that direction.